# Getting SSL / https working locally for Rails with puma-dev

Tags: ruby-on-rails, keychain, puma

[puma-dev](https://github.com/puma/puma-dev#https) should work with https / SSL with just the initial install `puma-dev -install` when you visit `https://yourlocalsitename.dev`.

I can see the certificate in Chrome > Dev Tools > Security but it says

```
This page is not secure (broken HTTPS).

Certificate Error
There are issues with the site's certificate chain (net::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID).
```

How can I get puma-dev working in https locally?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If the normal `puma-dev -install` doesn't work even after brew uninstall/install of puma-dev try this [recommended here](https://youtu.be/CJQrYJTlA8w?t=2m41s)

1. In *Chrome > Developer Tools > **Security*** click **View Certificate**
2. Drag the icon for the certificate to your OS X desktop
3. From your desktop, double click on the cert to install it in your *OS X > Keychain Access* as **System** (not login)
4. From Keychain Access, double click on the cert (in System) and change the dropdown to **Always Trust**

Now try visiting `https://yourlocalsitename.dev` again, but in a **new tab**, and it should be green for https.

Answer (score 4):

this is the most recent method.

```
security add-trusted-cert -k login.keychain-db ~/Library/Application\ Support/io.puma.dev/cert.pem
```

https://github.com/puma/puma-dev/issues/84#issuecomment-269588573

Answer (score 0):

In recent MacOS/X versions the drag-and-drop feature of the certificate doesn't work for Chrome:

- Do `openssl s_client -connect 127.0.0.1:443 -servername your.site.localhost -showcerts`. Interrupt when the certificate data is displayed.
- Create a file which content is the output of the previous command from the `--- BEGIN CERTIFICATE` line to the `--- END CERTIFICATE` line (including them).
- Do `sudo security add-trusted-cert -d -r trustRoot -k /Library/Keychains/System.keychain <certificate file>`
- Open Keychain Access application, find the certificate in the System Keychain and set the trust level to 'Always Trust'